# issue in sed command for extracting test between two words

Tags: bash, unix

my file is a.txt:

```
this is for testing
so test
againa and again
zzz and ssss
this is for testing
so test
againa and again
```

here I'm trying to extract test between zzz and test:

```
 cat a.txt | sed -n '/zzz/,/test/p'
```

output:

```
 zzz and ssss
 this is for testing
 so test
```

the issue is:

```
cat a.txt | sed -n '/zzz/,/jjj/p'
```

When I'm trying to keep some word (jjj) which is not present in the file, it is giving me data from `zzz` to end of the file. Ideally it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: What do you want if `jjj` isn't present? Don't print anything or print only `zzz`?

Comment: hi uzsolt  the above query will extract data between these words it starts from zzz till jjj. if jjj is not present it shouldnt give me the output as that particulat word jjj is not present in my file

Comment: How are you getting 3 lines of output for `sed -n '/zzz/,/test/p'? "test" occurs on the next line, so you should only get 2 lines out.

Answer (score 1):

sed is not as smart as you hope it is. You can use awk: after seeing the first regex, store the lines. When you hit the second regex, print out all the lines you've captured

```
awk -v regex1="zzz" -v regex2="jjj" '
    $0 ~ regex1 {start=1} 
    start {lines = lines $0 ORS} 
    start && $0 ~ regex2 {printf "%s", lines; exit}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -oP` will be better option here:

```
$ grep -oP 'zzz[\s\S]*test' a.txt 
zzz and ssss
this is for testing
so test

grep -oP 'zzz[\s\S]*jjj' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, just for fun :

```
[ ~]$ awk 'BEGIN{b=e=0; s=es=""} 
      ($0 ~ "^zzz.*"){b=1} 
      ($0 ~ ".*test$"){e=1; b=0; es=s; s=""; if(es!=""){es=es"\n"$0}else{es=$0}} 
      (b==1){if(s!=""){s=s"\n"$0}else{s=$0}} END {print es}' file
```

The output with the same input file :

```
zzz and ssss
this is for testing
so test
```

If you change ".*test$" by another pattern which is not corresponding to a word in the input file, this command will not produce output :

```
[ ~]$ awk 'BEGIN{b=e=0; s=es=""} 
      ($0 ~ "^zzz.*"){b=1} 
      ($0 ~ ".*jjj$"){e=1; b=0; es=s; s=""; if(es!=""){es=es"\n"$0}else{es=$0}} 
      (b==1){if(s!=""){s=s"\n"$0}else{s=$0}} END {print es}' file
[ ~]$
```

Of course, you can use the "-v" option to make the regexps easily configurables.

Otherwise, the proposition of anubhava with grep doesn't work with my laptop :

```
[neumann@MacBookPro ~]$ cat file
this is for testing
so test
againa and again
zzz and ssss
this is for testing
so test
againa and again
[neumann@MacBookPro ~]$ grep -oP 'zzz[\s\S]*test' file
[neumann@MacBookPro ~]$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
[neumann@MacBookPro ~]$
```

That's why, when I have a pattern with multiple lines, I'm doing this with awk.